# Open the kubernetes dashboard in Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, centos, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a virtual machine on Google cloud. I installed kubernetes on the virtual machine, it works fine. I want to access the kubernetes dashboard but cannot. how can I do it.

Comment: The tags you added to your question are a bit confusing. Have you installed open source kubernetes on **Google Compute Engine** virtual machine ? Or maybe you started a new instance of **Google Kubernetes Engine** cluster ? Please be more specific, also with tags you add to your question. If it's open source k8s, have you deployed the dashboard ? Is it running on your k8s cluster ? How exactly are you trying to access the dashboard and what error message do you receive ? _"I want to access the kubernetes dashboard but cannot."_ doesn't give us many details and reduces your chances to get help.

Comment: Hello, I have created a CentOS virtual machine on Google Compute Engine. I have installed kubernetes and prometheus in this machine. I need access to the Kubernetes dashboard and the prometheus dashboard. I need to access ports 8001 and 9090. I guess I need to setup a VPC network. I installed the control panel. there is no problem with my setup. I just want to access these ports.

Comment: OK, aren't those ports blocked on firewall ? You need allow the access explicitely. So as far as I understand when you `curl your-k8s-dashboard` from this **Compute Engine** VM, it works ? Is it exposed by any `Service` ? You should be able to expose it via `NodePort` and access your dashboard on random (or explicitely specified) port from `30000-32767` range.